# How to make a list item <li> act like a link <a>

Tags: html, css, listitem

I can't seem to figure out how you make an `<a>` inside a `<li>` element act like it takes the full element, so when you actually hover over the list item your mouse changes to a clickable region. Now i'm unable to change the text-color on hover over the list-item (only when I hover over the text) and unable to click on the list item (again only when I hover over the text). Any help is welcome!

```css
nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 3rem 0rem;
}

ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 40%;
}

li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans';
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: block;
}


a:hover{
  color: white;
}
li:hover{
  color: white;
  border-radius:1.5rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #363795, #005c97);
}
```

```html
<nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="./index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">activiteiten</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">extra</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add padding to `a` instead of `li`, and for the best practive, use [**inheritance**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance).

e.g. `nav ul li a:hover`

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 3rem 0rem;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 40%;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans';
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #363795, #005c97);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="./index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">activiteiten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">extra</a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can mark this as answer in some minutes! Thank you for the fast response! Appreciate it!

Comment: Didn't know you could it like this, I'm pretty noob with inheritance. What's the advantage of this if I may ask?

Comment: @LucasVerhoest I have updated my answer with MDN link, you can read more about it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Check This,

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 3rem 0rem;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 40%;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans';
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #363795, #005c97);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="./index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">activiteiten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">extra</a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much and for the fast response! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Add the padding to `a` instead of `li`, and then only apply hover to `a` - not to `li`.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 3rem 0rem;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 40%;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans';
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #363795, #005c97);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="./index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">activiteiten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">extra</a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much and for the fast response! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert `li`s into nested flex containers:

```css
nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 3rem 0rem;
}

ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 40%;
}

li{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex; /* now all the content of LI will take its whole area */
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans';
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  /* no need to set display since flex items are already blockified */
}


a:hover{
  color: white;
}
li:hover{
  color: white;
  border-radius:1.5rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #363795, #005c97);
}
```

```html
<nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="./index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">activiteiten</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">extra</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for sharing!